# JavaFX Packager overwrite/outsource memory params

Tags: java, memory, javafx, jvm, packager

We deploy our JavaFX Application with Java 8 and JavaFX Packager within an ANT-file.

During the build-process a new *application.cfg* is generated, which is called by the *application.exe* and includes information about the application's classpath, runtime, version etc. Moreover it includes information about the JVM Options like this for example:

```
...

[JVMOptions]
-Xmx1024m
-Xms128m

...
```

Unfortunatly I have no control about how the *application.exe* is started, so I can't pass any memory params for the jvm to it, but what I want to achieve is, that the customer can define their own parameter in a different file, which doesn't get overriden with each new update. Since I may have to update the *application.cfg*, when a new version is released I need to store those memory parameters somewhere else.

Is there any way to define those "-xmx/-xms" parameters in a different file?